# Category of words — 'another', 'an additional', "an alternative", etc

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

I'm afraid I've had a sudden lapse of memory and have forgotten what category these kinds of words belong to. These words are used to expand upon another point within the same category.

For example:

> - One factor
> - **An additional** factor
> - **Another** factor
> - **An alternative** factor

Comment: I'm not native of English language, but, as far as I know, these words are modifiers http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier

Answer (score 3):

Collins labels all non-pronoun usages of *another* as being in the determiner class, but keeps *additional* and *alternative* within the adjective class. The AHDEL keeps all three within the traditional adjective class.

Using the Wikipedia distinction:

A determiner is a noun-modifier that expresses the reference of a noun or noun-phrase in the context, rather than attributes expressed by adjectives.

one would suppose that all three (plus numerals and other quantifiers) would be better regarded as determiners.

Comment: The reason that *another* is a determiner and the others are not is because it has the article built right into it, whereas with *additional* and *alternative* you can still add a prefix article or number, like “an alternative” or “the three additional”. You cannot do that with *another*: neither *an* nor *the* may precede it.

Comment: "From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
"**The Another World**" redirects here. For the 1991 game, see Another World (video game).
"Ni no Kuni
Ni no Kuni (二の国?, lit. Second Country, also called **The Another World**) is a role-playing video game, co-developed by Japanese developer Level-5 and the first videogame made by anime company Studio Ghibli,[1] for the Nintendo DS and later PlayStation 3."

Comment: "Arjuna: **Into the Another World**
"From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia "Arjuna: **Into the Another World** is a soundtrack album for the anime Earth Girl Arjuna by Yoko Kanno."

Comment: **I Wish An Another Day** // [link](http://www.elyrics.net/read/m/mc-erik-&-barbara-lyrics/i-wish-an-another-day-lyrics.html)
"I wish an another day, to be with you again /
"I wanna call your name, I pray everyday /
"I wish an another day, so please can't you stay /
"To love me everyday, because I want you //

"I wish an another day.... //

"I wish an another day with you, my darlin' /
"I wish an another day with you, my loverboy /
"I wish an another day with you, my darlin' /
"I wish an another day with you, my loverboy //

"I wish an another day, to give our love one real picture..."

Comment: "You are here: Home / Reviews / #Beauty Box **Five Another** #Pitch List Review!" [link](http://couponsandfriends.com/2012/08/24/beauty-box-five-another-pitch-list-review/) _It's amazing what one **may** and **may not** do with English, isn't it? I guess these folks didn't get the memo that they mayn't put **an**, **the**, or a number (**five**) in front of **another**_.